# How to use pentaho kitchen to connect database repository?

Tags: etl, pentaho

How to use pentaho kitchen to connect my central database repository under commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up your connection in repositories.xml, you probably already have one of these if you have been using spoon. Make sure the repositories.xml exists in .kettle for the installation where you are running kitchen.

then simply use these command line options:

/rep "YOUR REPO NAME"
/user "REPO USER"
/pass "REPO PSS"

Comment: Also, make sure to add the path to kitchen in your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Below, an Windows script batch example to run a Pentaho Data Integration kettle Job :

```
@echo off    
SET LOG_PATHFILE=C:\logs\KITCHEN_name_of_job_%DATETIME%.log    

call Kitchen.bat /rep:"name_repository" /job:"name_of_job" /dir:/foo/sub_foo1 /user:dark /pass:vador /level:Detailed >> %LOG_PATHFILE%`
```

The repository ***"name_repository"*** must be defined in ***/users/.kettle/repositories.xml***. Juste below an example of this file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repositories>
  <connection>
    <name>name_repository</name>
    <server>hostname</server>
    <type>MYSQL</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>name_database_repository</database>
    <port>9090</port>
    <username>[name]</username>
    <password>[password]</password>
    <servername/>
    <data_tablespace/>
    <index_tablespace/>
    <attributes>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.defaultFetchSize</code><attribute>500</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.useCursorFetch</code><attribute>true</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_LOWERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_UPPERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>IS_CLUSTERED</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PORT_NUMBER</code><attribute>9090</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>QUOTE_ALL_FIELDS</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>STREAM_RESULTS</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>USE_POOLING</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
    </attributes>
  </connection>
  <repository>
    <id>KettleDatabaseRepository</id>
    <name>name_repository</name>
    <description>the pentaho data integraion kettle repository</description>
    <connection>name_repository</connection>
  </repository>
```